# CSS Trouble on Dropdowns

Tags: css, navigation, styles, drop-down-menu

uMy child pages are showing up in a horizontal line under the parent page link in the navigation. I can't figure out where the css is wrong. You can see what I'm talking about here (the links under Sample Page are the ones in question): http://sitetest3.talktothedogs.com.

HTML for Navigation (which is auto-generated by WP)

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
   <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://sitetest3.talktothedogs.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://sitetest3.talktothedogs.com/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a>
      <ul class='children'>
         <li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://sitetest3.talktothedogs.com/?page_id=4">Testing page 2</a></li>
         <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://sitetest3.talktothedogs.com/?page_id=6">Testing page 1</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code

```
.menu, .menu ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; height:29px; text-align:center; }
.menu a { color:#fff; display:block; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:0px; }
.menu a:hover { color:#000; display:block; text-decoration:none; }
.menu li { float:left; margin:0; padding: 0px; }
.menu li li { float:left; margin: 0 0 0 5px; padding:0; width:130px; }
.menu li ul.submenu li { display:block; position:absolute; left:0; }
.menu li li a, .menu li li a:link, .menu li li a:visited { background:#a82652; width:150px; float:none; margin:0; padding: 4px 10px 5px 10px; color:#fff; }
.menu li li a:hover, .menu-header li li a:active { background:#000; width:150px; float: none; margin: 0; padding: 4px 10px 5px 10px; color:#fff; }
.menu li ul { position:absolute; width:10em; left:-999em; padding-top:13px; z-index:1; }
.menu li:hover ul { left:auto; display:block; }
.menu li:hover ul, #menu li.sfhover ul { left: auto; }
.menu li.current_page_item a { } 
.menu li.current_page_item a:hover{ }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it you want? Do you want them vertical? How are you looking to fix this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want them to be vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS as follows:

```
.menu li a{ margin-bottom:13px;}
.menu li li { float:none; margin: 0; padding:0; width:130px; }
```

Here is how this would look
[image: Here is how this would look]

Answer (score 0):

Your first line in the CSS:

```
.menu, .menu ul { ... }
```

is setting the height of both the `<div class="menu">` **AND** the `<ul>` within that .menu to the same height. The entire menu is constrained to a container that's 29px high.